# Kotlin: lost of 'this' context in a Timertask Handler

Tags: kotlin, scope, timertask

I have this sample of code I use to test a light in a project of mine, written in Kotlin.

```
fun Light.test() {
    val open = this.isOpen()
    this.setOpen(!open)
    val that = this
    Timer().schedule(500) {
        that.setOpen(open)
    }
}
```

See, with `Timer().schedule(500)`, in the lambda, I seem to be losing the scope of `this`, and `this` becomes the `timertask` itself, instead of the `Light` object.

I found a solution using the good old fashion `val that = this` learned from 2010 Javascript, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this in Kotlin.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is special syntax such that you can access the preferred this in any context. In your case you could use:

```kotlin
fun Light.test() {
    val open = isOpen()
    setOpen(!open)
    Timer().schedule(500) {
        this@test.setOpen(open)
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it fixed your problem!